# How to show parent category title in featured articles on the home page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, subcategories, featured-articles

My home page has the featured article view in 3 columns. There are parent categories like news, teledrama and programmes. I want to categorise these featured articles. News articles should be under title news. Teledrama articles should be under title Teledrama, likewise I want to categorise my front page. Could you please tell me how to do it???

[image: this is what my front page(featured articles view) look like]

[image: this is what i really want(categorise featured articles page)]

**UPDATE**
Thank you all for your answers.

But this is not the thing i want to know, featured article layout is already sorted as category order. But I want is to add **parent category title**  over each and every category.

As @Anibal said, I also think the place is this (image attached).
[image: is this the file to edit]

I also fond a useful article: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2541194

In that article it says that I can get **parent category title name** using **$this->item->parent_title**.

Please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 2):

If your template does not recognize any of usual options to enable the parent category, you can create a new layout override to include it specifically: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Layouts

- /templates
- _ /beez
- ____       /html
- **________**         /com_content  (this directory matches the component directory name)
- **_____________**               /articles        (this directory matches the view directory name)
- **_____________**                 default.php (this file matches the layout file name)

Answer (score 1):

It should be a matter of assigning each featured article to a specific category, then displaying these chosen categories on your page. Change the article global config options;

You can find The global options for the configuration of a blog page on:

- Content->Article Manger->Options (from the topmenu);
- The tabs for all the global options is on the right side of the
  window:

Acrticles, Editing Layout, Category, Categories, Blog / Featured Layouts, List Layouts, Shared Options, Integration and Permissions.
Select Blog / Featured Layouts.

On this page you can set the global options for the Blog / Featured layout.

- Leading Articles: The number of full width articles.
- Intro Articles: The number of articles you want to show after the
  leading articles.
- Columns: The number of columns you want for the intro articles.
- Links: The number of articles you want to link to if there are more
  articles in the category.

The tutorial here may help also www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/blog-multiple-categories
[Blog multiple categories](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/blog-multiple-categories/)

I think this is what you are looking to day anyway, apologies if I misunderstood!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

But this is not the thing i want to know, featured article layout is already sorted as category order. But I want is to add **parent category title**  over each and every category.

As @Anibal said, I also think the place is this (image attached).
[image: is this the file to edit]

I also fond a useful article: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2541194

In that article it says that I can get **parent category title name** using **$this->item->parent_title**.

Please tell me how to do it